# How do I connect to Astra DB from my flutter application's login page?

Tags: flutter, dart, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am currently working on a flutter application using dart language. I am trying to use AstraDB for my login page authentication of users' email and password using the http flutter package.

The following are the code I used for creating the the data in AstraDB as well as for the application, for the api urls I have followed the same format as indicated with my respective values and "users" is the name of my table in AstraDB.

CQL command used to create the table in AstraDB Console:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  email text PRIMARY KEY,
  password text
);
```

CQL command used to insert data in AstraDB Console:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('john@example.com', 'password123');
```

Dart code for the application's login page in Android Studio:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AstraDB HTTP Demo',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _login() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://YOUR-ASTRA-DB-ID-YOUR-ASTRA-DB-REGION.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/keyspace_name/users?apiToken=YOUR-APPLICATION-TOKEN'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            'X-Cassandra-Token:YOUR-APPLICATION-TOKEN',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'email': _emailController.text,
        'password': _passwordController.text,
      }),
    );

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Login Successful');
      // TODO: Handle successful login.
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to log in.');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _signup() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://YOUR-ASTRA-DB-ID-YOUR-ASTRA-DB-REGION.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v1/signup'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            'X-Cassandra-Token:YOUR-APPLICATION-TOKEN,
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'email': _emailController.text,
        'password': _passwordController.text,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Signup Successful');
      // TODO: Handle successful signup.
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to sign up.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AstraDB HTTP Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _signup,
              child: Text('Sign Up'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Firstly, when trying running the application on my tablet and typing in the respective values in the login fields, it provides me with the following message in Android Studios' terminal.

```
E/flutter (28320): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to log in.
E/flutter (28320): #0      _LoginPageState._login (package:sign_in/main.dart:42:7)
E/flutter (28320): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Secondly, I tried checking if the ApiURL was correct using my web browser (Google Chrome) and it provided this error on the page. I am not sure if this is the correct way to check.

```
{"description":"where parameter is required","code":400}
```

I expected the application's login to be successful upon filling in the appropriate details, allowing the user to proceed to use the rest of the application features. I initially wanted to add a sign up feature as well but my login itself does not work itself. However, this was not the case and I have been trying to find a solution for this for approximately two weeks now. All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to access the data in table `users`. There a couple of things to update.

**Table Design**

To authenticate user we want to execute the query `select email,password from users` as such both email and password should be part of the key. The table should be changed to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
 email text,
 password text,
 PRIMARY KEY((email), password)
);
```

In the table make sure you do not store the password in clear text but rather encode it in SHA1 for security reason.

**The Query**

- To use HTTP API, You will need an authentication key to be passed in the header. (this is the cause of your error above). To create one [follow the instructions](https://awesome-astra.github.io/docs/pages/astra/create-token/#c-procedure)
- If you look at the Swagger UI available in Astra UI your are targeting this resource

```
[GET] /v2/keyspaces/{keyspaceName}/{tableName}
```

- The where clause you need is

```
where={ 'email': {'$eq': 'john@example.com'},  'password': {'$eq': 'password123'}}
```

- But as it is a GET request the parameter needs to be encoded and the full request looks like:

```
curl -s -L -X GET 'https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/demo/users?where=%7B%20%22email%22%3A%20%7B%22%24eq%22%3A%20%22john%40example.com%22%7D%20%2C%20%22password%22%3A%20%7B%22%24eq%22%3A%20%22password123%22%7D%20%7D' \
-H "X-Cassandra-Token:${ASTRA_TOKEN}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json"
```

The output look like:

```
{"count":1,"data":[{"email":"john@example.com","password":"password123"}]}
```

I propose you to use the field to tell if authentication is successful or not.

Comment: How do I encode the password with SHA1? I did similar steps for the HTTP API, do i need to use the client id and secret? Is swaggerui and curl used to test if the authentication is successful or not on the application or on the web browser? Sorry, I am really new to this and am learning.

Comment: Encore with SHA1: It is part of the dart language https://pub.dev/packages/crypto#usage

Comment: Do i need to use the client id and secret? => For the REST APi use the TOKEN in the header as described above -H "X-Cassandra-Token:${ASTRA_TOKEN}". CliendId and clientSecret are for CQL access.

Comment: Is swaggerui and curl ...? => Swagger UI is used in the browser from the Astra User interface whereas curl is used in a terminal on your machine., 2 different tools.

Comment: Thank you, I used Swagger UI to provide the url link and I replace my old endpoint with this in the login page code. These are examples of a few lines of output on my Android Studio terminal, any idea what my mistake is?
E/flutter ( 4280): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Error on line 1, column 34: Invalid media type: expected no more input.
E/flutter ( 4280):   ╷
E/flutter ( 4280): 1 │ application/jsonX-Cassandra-Token:abcdefg

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the authentication token in the header section. In your app, you have incorrectly included the token in the URI which is incorrect.

To illustrate, here are the contents of my `users` table:

```
 email          | password
----------------+------------
 alice@mail.com | Wonder7and
```

WARNING: I stored the password in plain text for simplicity but this is not recommended. Best practice is to hash-encode the password before saving it.

The API endpoint I use to query is (note the `@` symbol in the email address is HTTP-encoded):

```
/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/community/users/alice%40mail.com
```

The headers are:

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-Cassandra-Token: abCdeFG...uVWx0z
```

This will return the following response:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "email": "alice@mail.com",
      "password": "Wonder7and"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to replicate the users table you have created but the "@mail" portion is not HTTP-encoded, is it a separate command to do so? Secondly, I tried to query the updated API endpoint following your example on my web browser, however it gives me the following error , {"description":"Role unauthorized for operation: Missing token","code":401} . Finally, will the response be shown on the web browser or the Android Studio console? Sorry, I am new to coding and AstraDB.

Comment: You can't use your browser to access the endpoint because you won't be able to specify the token in the headers. This is why you get the authentication error. You have to do it in your app. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

METHOD 1: Using the `WHERE` clause

The `WHERE` clause is used to query data with  a specified search term. To implement Log In, you can use the `$eq` search term in your query string parameter to fetch data for a specific user, using the URI below:

`https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/schemas/keyspaces/${ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/${TABLE_NAME}/?where=${PARAM}`

For additional information on search terms, [see the Datastax documentation.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-rest.html#_read_data)

Example:

```
  Future<void> _login() async {
    final astraToken = <YOUR_ASTRA_TOKEN>
    final encodedParam = jsonEncode({
      "email": {"\$eq": <EMAIL_FROM_TEXTFIELD>},
    });

    final response = await http.get(  Uri.parse('https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/schemas/keyspaces/${ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/${TABLE_NAME}/?where=$encodedParam'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'X-Cassandra-Token': astraToken,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Login Successful');
      print(response.body);
      // TODO: Handle successful login.
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception('Failed to log in.');
    }
}
```

If the queried email exists, you'll get a response that looks like this:

```
{"count":1,"data":[{"email":"user@mail.com","password":"123"}]}
```

You can then compare the password value from the response against the value from the text field to authenticate the user.

```
 ...

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map decodedResponseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final String password = decodedResponseData['data'][0]['password'];
      if(password == <PASSWORD_FROM_TEXTFIELD>){
        print('Login successful');
       // TODO: Handle successful login.
      }
      else{
        throw Exception('incorrect password');
      }
    
    } else {
      print(response.body);

      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception('Failed to log in.');
    }
 ...
```

METHOD 2: Adding the primary key to the URI path

The only difference here is the URI. The primary key, which is the `email`, should be added to the URI as a path.

`https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/schemas/keyspaces/${ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/${TABLE_NAME}/${EMAIL_FROM_TEXTFIELD}`

Example:

```
 Future<void> _login() async {
    final astraToken = <YOUR_ASTRA_TOKEN>

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/schemas/keyspaces/${ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/${TABLE_NAME}/${EMAIL_FROM_TEXTFIELD}'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'X-Cassandra-Token': astraToken,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Login Successful');
      print(response.body);
      // TODO: Handle successful login.
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception('Failed to log in.');
    }
}
```

For sign up, the mistake you made was with the URI and the status code check. You should use this URI instead:

`https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/schemas/keyspaces/${ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/${TABLE_NAME}`

As for the status code, you should be checking for `201` (created) instead of `200` (OK).

```
...
 if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  print('Signup Successful');
  print(response.body);
  // TODO: Handle successful signup.
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to sign up.');
}
...
```

TODO:

1. Separate UI from business logic
2. Hash passwords